# Error in installation of quorum blockchain

Tags: blockchain, quorum

## Error in installing the quorum

> github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto/secp256k1 exec: "gcc":
>   executable file not found in $PATH
>   github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/karalabe/hid #
>   github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/karalabe/hid exec:
>   "gcc": executable file not found in $PATH util.go:44: exit status 2
>   exit status 1 Makefile:25: recipe for target 'all' failed make: ***
>   [all] Error 1

`

Answer (score 0):

Install gcc

```
$ apt-get install build-essential
```

or

```
$ apt-get install gcc
```

After that you can run make all it will run.